# Arranging movable UI components

Tags: android, layout, components, android-layout, move

Basically I'm just starting out with Android development (though I have a fairly extensive Java background) and I'm having difficulty working out how I could build this user interface where the components move in (like the arrows indicate) in this order:

1. The bottom image moves upwards and then stops
2. The first image moves right and over the top of the bottom image
3. The image below this moves left over the top of the bottom image

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1wou.png

I've been really pulling my hair out about how I could do this and I've read the API fairly extensively for a solution because its clearly a simple problem but I honestly cant work it out. I'm not even sure which layout manager to start with!

Thanks,
Samuel

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial for animations:

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

If you want the animations to start one after the other you should use:

```
View viewN = ..;
Animation animN = ...;
animN.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
// ...
void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
{
// Start Animation2;

});
```